# setState() block the UI when two setState() run

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate, react-state-management, react-state

Here is my `componentDidMount()` method :

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const subscription = accelerometer.subscribe(({ x, y, z, timestamp }) => {
        x = Math.trunc(x*100);
        this.setState({x})
    });
}
```

In above method, every 100 millisecond state is changing. I used that state in my `render()` method as below :

```js
render() {
    const animatedImageStyle = StyleSheet.flatten([
      styles.captureButton,
      {
        transform: [{rotateZ:this.state.x + 'deg'}]
      }
    ])

    return (
      <SideMenu 
        menu={leftMenu}
        isOpen={this.state.isOpenLeftMenu}
        menuPosition={'left'}
        bounceBackOnOverdraw={false}
        onChange={(isOpenLeftMenu) => this.updateLeftMenuState(isOpenLeftMenu)}
      >
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity 
                activeOpacity={0.5}
                onPress={(this.state.recordingMode == 'camera')?() => this.takePicture():() => this.toggleRecording()}
              > 
                <Image 
                  source={require('../assets/imgs/forRotate.png')}
                  style={animatedImageStyle}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </SideMenu>
    )
}
```

Now, the problem is that when I trying to open sidemenu, it is not opening, I mean it opening but hanging too much. My whole app hanging too much.

I think that's because of below method :

```js
updateLeftMenuState(isMenuOpen) {
    this.setState({
      isOpenLeftMenu:isMenuOpen
    })
}
```

Notice that I am updating another state called `isOpenLeftMenu`, which may blocked during I update state `x`.

Can anyone tell me what't going wrong here ?

Comment: Every time you set the state, the views have to get redrawn. That means you're destroying and redrawing your interface 10 times per second, which is pretty computationally heavy. Try slowing down the frequency of state changes.

Comment: I can not slow down the frequency of state changes, because 100 milliseconds is requirement. Btw I slowdown to 1 seconds still not worked.

Comment: can you check to skip the setState until you get different values? like we don't need to set state if we have to set same value again as it's already set.

Comment: That's nice idea @Ashish but, but in my app a functionality in which i rotate button according to device rotation( not only portrait to landscape but base on rotation deg) so I need every milliseconds value.

Comment: @KishanBharda try with a component variable. Setting state will remount the component every time. and if you'll define it in component var like `this.x = x`. if it may help.

Comment: @Ashish If I use `this.x` in my component then changes does not effect the component. So I will not get my desired output.

Comment: I think the issue is because of the async behavior of the setState function. The accelerometer event might be triggering before the previous setState function is called so there will stack of pending setState function on successive events.

Comment: @MohammedAshfaq Please can you tell me how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can move the animation view in a separate component along with subscription logic. So the state update of that component won't affect the SideMenu component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this help me to only settings state in perfect way but not solved my main issue.

Comment: you can move the animation view in a separate component along with subscription logic and Try.

Comment: Yes. Absolute right @MohammedAshafaq. Moving animation view in a separate component worked for me. Thank You. Please edit answer with above comment so I can accept it and will help someone.